# RecordTypeId in Account - there is one on an account that is not in the list in the UI

Tags: soql, account

We have a client who's website we integrated with their Salesforce account.

In order to login to their website, the website CMS user's email address has to match a contact in a valid Organization (Account).

One of the checks is to see if the associated Account is one of two possible RecordTypeIds

We have someone who can't log in to the CMS, because the Account associated with their Salesforce contact has a RecordTypeId that is *not* one of the ones listed on /ui/setup/rectype/RecordTypes?type=Account

Where would this different RecordTypeId be coming from?  Is there some other listing of possible RecordTypeIds for Accounts somewhere?

Comment: Certain `RecordType` options can be disabled for your `Profile`. You wouldn't be able to select them when creating records through the UI, but you would still be able to see them in setup...

Comment: It's not 000000000000000AAA, is it? That's the "master" record type that always exists, but is never listed.

Comment: Heh. That would be tricky. Can you query for it? @sfdcfox

Comment: No, it's not the master record type. It's a usual looking complex id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

The RecordTypeId in question *is* listed in the UI; I just didn't recognize it because the SOQL query result in the developer console tacks a few extra characters onto it. A phenomenon that I am fully aware of, but apparently forgot this time.